# Explanation of how heap memory works (Java)

Tags: java, jsp, heap-memory

I read something on the internet but I'm not sure I get it.

I created a little website that's host by a cheap server with 128mb of heap memory.
When I start the server and i visit the first page I have these values (I get them by using `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` and `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`):

1. total memory:128974848
2. used  memory:42376200
3. free  memory:86598648

After seeing some pages (some times few, some times many) the total memory decreases. After seeing other pages it increases.

I can't understand if this is the way the heap memory behaves or if there's something wrong in my code.

Comment: The *total* memory decreases; do you mean the *free* memory?

Comment: I mean the total memory!!! That's why I'm asking if there's a problem according to you.

Comment: How are you measuring these numbers?

Comment: By using Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()  and Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty normal. Different web pages will use different amounts of memory based on the content they have in them. Where I would be worried is if you keep opening pages and memory never gets freed. That is a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and is cause for concern if you are developing web browsers.

It is also possible that total memory may decrease because the server keeps information about who requests web pages out of convenience, so it can serve them faster in the future. An example would be Amazon's way of storing what products you search so it can suggest other items while you're browsing.

Comment: It's not necessarily a memory leak.  The process may be hanging on to committed memory out of convenience.  Memory usage (as viewed from the OS perspective) is complicated.

Comment: Ah, true. I will add that.

Comment: Then, according to what both of you are saying maybe there isn't an error in my code when I see a decrease of Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() but it's just the behave of the heap memory? Right?

Comment: Now that I've seen that this is specifically about Java, and using Java's reporting of memory usage, I don't believe this answers the question.  Why does *total* memory go down (as opposed to free memory)?

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand if this is the way the heap memory behaves

Yes, this is the gist of how any garbage-collection-based system would behave.

The principle behind garbage collection is that objects are not explicitly deleted or cleared when they are no longer needed.  Rather, they simply go out of scope (that is, no live objects continue to refer to them).  And for some non-zero period, these objects will still exist in memory.

Periodically, the garbage collector will run, and it will find these unreachable objects and *actually* remove them from memory.  The exact details of how often the garbage collector runs, and how hard it tries to find garbage, depend entirely on the exact algorithm and any tuning parameters (and can make a significant difference to the performance of an application).  In general though, they tend to run more often when there's less free memory left, and vice versa.

The gist is that even if your "real" memory usage is more or less static, you'll probably see a sawtooth type pattern, as temporary objects are created, and hang around for a while until the garbage collector runs and gets rid of them.  That's entirely normal.

Comment: How does that explain `totalMemory` decreasing?  (As opposed to `freeMemory`, for example.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but what's it's not clear it's the decrease of the total memory.